# d3: Draw children once, but update every time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a graph with multiple pie charts and, per chart, two center `tspan` labels inside one `text` container. Individual data for each sub-graph is supplied and initial drawing works.

However, the `tspan` contents don't get updated when clicking one of the setX buttons - in contrast to the arcs (whose code I have hidden here).

When I replace `var centerTextGroup = ggEnter.append("text")` by `var centerTextGroup = graphGroup.append("text")`, however, then `drawChart` paints a *new* text group element, which I don't want either.

How do I solve this issue and make drawCharts update the tspans properly?

Edit: one solution may be to use `graphGroup.selectAll("text").remove();` before `var centerTextGroup = graphGroup.append("text")`, and it works, but I strongly suspect this isn't the d3 way of doing things...

```js
var config = {
  width: 150,
  height: 100,
  circleYCenter: 50,
  circleXCenter: 75,
  circleRad: 50,
  circleWidth: 15,
  arcWidth: 20,
};
var svgContainer = null;

function drawCharts(data) {
  var container = svgContainer.select("#bigCircleGroup");
  var graphGroup = container.selectAll("g.graphGroup").data(data);
  var ggEnter = graphGroup.enter().append("g").attr({
    transform: function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + (config.width * i) + ",0)";
    },
    class: "graphGroup",
    id: function(d, i) {
      return "bigCircle" + i;
    }
  });
  graphGroup.exit().remove();

  //Standard, common background arc. Append to enter selection, needs only to be drawn once per graph
  var circleArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(config.circleRad - (config.circleWidth / 2)).outerRadius(config.circleRad + (config.circleWidth / 2)).startAngle(0).endAngle(Math.PI * 2);
  ggEnter.append("path").attr({
    "d": circleArc,
    "transform": "translate(" + (config.circleXCenter) + "," + (config.circleYCenter) + ")",
    "stroke": "none",
    "fill": "#ececec"
  });

  //Label. Group and labels should be drawn once per graph, but updated every time
  var centerTextGroup = ggEnter.append("text").attr({
    "x": config.circleXCenter,
    "y": config.circleYCenter,
    "class": "center"
  }).style({
    "text-anchor": "middle",
    "alignment-baseline": "baseline",
    "font-size": "30px",
    "fill": "#5d5d5d"
  });
  var bigDigitLabel = centerTextGroup.append("tspan").style("alignment-baseline", "baseline").attr("class", "bigDigit").text(function(d) {
    return d.text.center;
  });
  var unitLabel = centerTextGroup.append("tspan").style("font-size", "20px").attr("dy", 0).text(function(d) {
    return d.text.unit;
  });

  //Draw arcs here (removed for brevity)
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  svgContainer = d3.select("svg");
  $("#set1").click(function() {
    drawCharts([{
      "data": [{
        "value": "0.5",
        "color": "pink"
      }, {
        "value": "0.3",
        "color": "lightblue"
      }],
      "text": {
        "center": 50,
        "unit": "%"
      }
    }, {
      "data": [{
        "value": "0.7",
        "color": "pink"
      }, {
        "value": "0.3",
        "color": "lightblue"
      }],
      "text": {
        "center": 70,
        "unit": "%"
      }
    }]);
  }).click();
  $("#set2").click(function() {
    drawCharts([{
      "data": [{
        "value": "0.1",
        "color": "pink"
      }, {
        "value": "0.05",
        "color": "lightblue"
      }],
      "text": {
        "center": 10,
        "unit": "%"
      }
    }, {
      "data": [{
        "value": "1",
        "color": "pink"
      }, {
        "value": "0",
        "color": "lightblue"
      }],
      "text": {
        "center": 100,
        "unit": "%"
      }
    }]);
  });
  $("#set3").click(function() {
    drawCharts([{
      "data": [{
        "value": "0.1",
        "color": "pink"
      }, {
        "value": "0.5",
        "color": "lightblue"
      }],
      "text": {
        "center": 10,
        "unit": "%"
      }
    }]);
  });
  $("#set4").click(function() {
    drawCharts([{
      "data": [{
        "value": "0.1",
        "color": "pink"
      }, {
        "value": "0.5",
        "color": "lightblue"
      }],
      "text": {
        "center": 10,
        "unit": "%"
      }
    }, {
      "data": [{
        "value": "0.1",
        "color": "pink"
      }, {
        "value": "0.5",
        "color": "lightblue"
      }],
      "text": {
        "center": 10,
        "unit": "%"
      }
    }, {
      "data": [{
        "value": "0.9",
        "color": "pink"
      }, {
        "value": "0.1",
        "color": "lightblue"
      }],
      "text": {
        "center": 10,
        "unit": "%"
      }
    }, ]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=450 height=100 style="display:block;">
  <g id="bigCircleGroup"></g>
</svg>
<button id="set1">set1</button>
<button id="set2">set2</button>
<button id="set3">set3</button>
<button id="set4">set4</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for data that changes, `enter` applies to new data points. There is a figurative `update` that can be applied to changed data points before `enter`, or, as is [often the case](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218), to newly `enter`ed AND existing datapoints' elements, and finally `exit` applies to data points that were removed. So it gets a little more complicated but if you can clean up and reuse how you setup data after it enters and put that in for the `update` step after `enter`, you can get more in line with how d3 is trying to help you write data driven documents. Also there's ways to enable an on click function with just d3 and no jquery, however I'll assume other parts of the page use jquery so it's effectively free for you.

```js
var dataSets = [
  // Set One: 2 Datapoints
  [{
 "data": [{"value": "0.5","color": "pink"},
          {"value": "0.3","color": "lightblue"}],
 "text": {"center": 50, "unit": "%"}
  },{
 "data": [{"value": "0.7", "color": "pink"},
          {"value": "0.3", "color": "lightblue"}],
 "text": {"center": 70, "unit": "%"}
  }],
  // Set Two: 2 Datapoints
  [{
 "data": [{"value": "0.1", "color": "pink"},
          {"value": "0.05", "color": "lightblue"}],
 "text": {"center": 10, "unit": "%"}
 }, {
 "data": [{"value": "1", "color": "pink"},
          {"value": "0", "color": "lightblue"}],
 "text": {"center": 100, "unit": "%"}
  }],
  // Set Three: 1 Datapoints
  [{
 "data": [{"value": "0.1", "color": "pink"},
          {"value": "0.5", "color": "lightblue"}],
 "text": {"center": 10, "unit": "%"}
  }],
  // Set Four: 3 Datapoints
  [{
 "data": [{"value": "0.1", "color": "pink"},
          {"value": "0.5", "color": "lightblue"}],
 "text": {"center": 10, "unit": "%"}
  },{
 "data": [{"value": "0.1", "color": "pink"},
          {"value": "0.5", "color": "lightblue"}],
 "text": {"center": 10, "unit": "%"}
  },{
 "data": [{"value": "0.9", "color": "pink"},
          {"value": "0.1", "color": "lightblue"}],
 "text": {"center": 10, "unit": "%"}
  }]];

 var config = {
   width: 150,
   height: 100,
   circleYCenter: 50,
   circleXCenter: 75,
   circleRad: 50,
   circleWidth: 15,
   arcWidth: 20,
 };
 var svgContainer = null;

 function drawCharts(setIndex) {
   var container = svgContainer.select("#bigCircleGroup");
   var graphGroup = container.selectAll("g.graphGroup").data(dataSets[setIndex]);
   var ggEnter = graphGroup.enter().append("g").attr({
     transform: function(d, i) {
       return "translate(" + (config.width * i) + ",0)";
     },
     class: "graphGroup",
     id: function(d, i) {
       return "bigCircle" + i;
     }
   });

   //Standard, common background arc. Append to enter selection, needs only to be drawn once per graph
   var circleArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(config.circleRad - (config.circleWidth / 2)).outerRadius(config.circleRad + (config.circleWidth / 2)).startAngle(0).endAngle(Math.PI * 2);
   ggEnter.append("path").attr({
     "d": circleArc,
     "transform": "translate(" + (config.circleXCenter) + "," + (config.circleYCenter) + ")",
     "stroke": "none",
     "fill": "#ececec"
   });

   //Label. Group and labels should be drawn once per graph, but updated every time
   ggEnterText = ggEnter.append("text");
   ggEnterText.append("tspan").attr("class", "bigDigit");
   ggEnterText.append("tspan").attr("class", "unit");
   graphGroup.exit().remove(); // No need to update items that will be removed.
   setText(graphGroup.select("text")); // Notice:
     // this applies to newly appended items that were entered
     // and to existing items that were not entered and need updating.

   //Draw arcs here (removed for brevity)
   // [probably need to handle both append and update as labels do]
 }

 function setText(selection) {
   selection = selection.transition();
   selection.attr({
     "x": config.circleXCenter,
     "y": config.circleYCenter,
     "class": "center"
   }).style({
     "text-anchor": "middle",
     "alignment-baseline": "baseline",
     "font-size": "30px",
     "fill": "#5d5d5d"
   });
   selection.select(".bigDigit").style("alignment-baseline", "baseline").text(function(d) {
     return d.text.center;
   });
   selection.select(".unit").style("font-size", "20px").attr("dy", 0).text(function(d) {
     return d.text.unit;
   });
 }


 $(document).ready(function() {
   svgContainer = d3.select("svg");
   $("#set1").click(function() {drawCharts(0);}).click();
   $("#set2").click(function() {drawCharts(1);});
   $("#set3").click(function() {drawCharts(2);});
   $("#set4").click(function() {drawCharts(3);});
 });
```

```css
.ref {width:100%;padding:1em 5em;}
.ref a{font-family:sans-serif;font-size:2em;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <svg width=450 height=100 style="display:block;">
      <g id="bigCircleGroup"></g>
    </svg>
    <button id="set1">set1</button>
    <button id="set2">set2</button>
    <button id="set3">set3</button>
    <button id="set4">set4</button>
<div class="ref"><a href="https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218">See Also</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The D3 way is:

```
1 - enter - incoming elements, entering the stage.
2 - update - persistent elements, staying on stage.
3 - exit - outgoing elements, exiting the stage.
```

You need the update. Thats why you must remove and recreate to update

Look at this: [Three Little Circles](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/)